# Visual Studio Web Deploy prompts for password when mode is Release, but not Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2013, release, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

We have a web project set up to deploy the same project to a handful of azure websites. When deploying to these websites, deployment in Debug mode works as expected. However when trying to deploy the same project to a website in Release mode, we are always prompted for a password.

Have tried deleting the .pubxml and .pubxml.user files, but the issue persists. Why would it deploy OK in Debug mode, but prompt for a password in Release mode?

Note: most of these projects deploy to virtual directories marked as applications in these websites. Other projects deploy just fine in release and debug mode, it seems to be just one project we are having issues with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still not sure why this was only happening with one of the virtual directory applications on the site, but going to the azure portal and clicking "Reset your publish profile credentials" seems to have fixed it.

Comment: sometimes its the reverse- where Release works and Debug prompts for credentials.  I'm really hoping that 2015 is better (i'll be upgrading in Sept)

Comment: Still broken in VS 2015 as of 4/21/2017.

Comment: I just had this happen in VS2017 after copying the project files from one computer to another. Resetting the publish profile isn't fixing it.

Answer (score 6):

This happend on VS 2017 when I tryied to update a setting in the profile.  The next time I tried to publish, the password was wacked and it started prompting me.

I realized that deleting the profile from within the Publish UI in VS did not work either because all it does is remove the .Pubxml from the project without deleting it from the HD and Source control.  Furthermore, if you don't delete the file manually, importing the setting whill leave you hanging; literally.

Again, the solution is to delete the file manually (both from the HD and from source control).  Then importing it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had an issue in VS 2013 and removing publishing profiles, restarting Visual Studio and selecting to publish to Azure worked.

Comment: Legendary, thanks @RashadRivera. Deleting the pubxml was the missing link.